# Can't run mysqld in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, permissions, mysql, 22.04, process

I try to run mysqld but i get following error in Ubuntu terminal.

```
2022-08-30T18:48:34.596763Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2022-08-30T18:48:34.596796Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 2510
2022-08-30T18:48:34.597987Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2022-08-30T18:48:34.597992Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
2022-08-30T18:48:34.602565Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-30T18:48:34.602646Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
```

When I try to change permission to `/var/lib/mysql` path by `sudo chown -R mysql /var/lib/mysql` I get error:

`chown: invalid user: ‘mysql’`

I am trying to learn Ubuntu/Linux so these are my first steps in this system.

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve.  `mysqld` is a server program, normally started at boot.  You can check its state by running `service mysql status`.  Similarly, to start it, use `service mysql start`  If you want to connect to a MySQL server, then use 'mysql' and its options.

Comment: How did you installed MySQL (server/client) and which command produces these error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Try running your command as root (using `sudo`)

```
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

And to confirm it's started try running

```
sudo systemctl status mysql
```